# Ionic 3 Native - LinkedIn login not working

Tags: android, linkedin-api, ionic3

I am using linkedin native plugin in ionic 2. this is what I did:

1- created a new app on linkedin.

2- Under the mobile section, pasted package name from config.xml file and then generated hash using the following command:

```
 keytool -exportcert -alias ALIAS_HERE -keystore path/to/mykey.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

and pasted the hash in the package hash.

now when I am trying to call login method, it's not firing up at all.

but `getActiveSession()` is working

How can I solve this issue ?

this is my code :

```
import { LinkedIn } from '@ionic-native/linkedin';

constructor(private linkedin: LinkedIn) { }

...

var scopes:any = ['r_basicprofile', 'r_emailaddress', 'rw_company_admin', 'w_share'];

this.linkedin.login(scopes, true).then((res) => {
          console.log(res) ;
}, (err) => {
            console.log(err) ;
});
```

Comment: Are you testing this on browser or?

Comment: No I'm testing on device

Comment: Any console errors on device?

Comment: Nothing and the code after it is executed

Comment: did you get an answer?

Comment:  no one did answer me